# Looping with while function with Selenium throws error NameError: name 'neadaclick' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a task in my work. I already have the task and every time I click on the program I can accomplish it, however I would want to be able to do the tasks several times with one click so I want to enter a loop using while. So I started testing, this is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
def countdown(n):
    while (n >= 0):
#Lets get rid of this
#        print (n)
        browser.get('http://www.simplesite.com/')
        needaclick = browser.find_element_by_id('startwizard')
        neadaclick.click()
        n = n - 1
    print ('Sucess!')
#Change from static to user input.
#countdown (10) 
countdown (int(input('Enter a real number:')))
#Failed script code, leaving it here for documentation
#int(countdown) = input('Enter a real number:')
```

As you can see I have a simple countdown and in theory (or at least in my mind) what should happen is that the number of times that I input should be the number of times that the program should open a browser and click on the element startwizard. But, I keep getting the error `needaclick` is not defined and I am unsure of how to fix this properly.

Error code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/AMSUser/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Scripts/Countdown Test.py", line 14, in 
>       countdown (int(input('Enter a real number:')))
>     File "C:/Users/AMSUser/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Scripts/Countdown Test.py", line 9, in countdown
>       neadaclick.click()
>   NameError: name 'neadaclick' is not defined

Comment: Show us the entire error traceback.  You're making us guess where the error happened.

Comment: Updated question, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: `needaclick = browser.find_element_by_id('startwizard')` vs `neadaclick.click()` - can you see it? **NEED** vs **NEAD**

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo yeah, well spotted, voted to close.

Comment: Thanks alecxe and @ElmoVanKielmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ElmoVanKielmo pointed out a mistake that i failed to notice, my first declaration is needaclick but on the next line i wrote neadaclick, this has been solved and its working.